# Regarding (how to overwrite the old.zip to new.zip files) if the files exists

Tags: c#

Here's the problem regarding to my question

the scenario
I have 2 folder, Path and Destination folder
then in destination I have already their a old zip files name (old.zip)
if ever i recopy the same zip it says the file is already exist.

the question is. how to overwrite the old.zip to new.zip files.

```
string filepath = @"C:\Users\orly.simbulan\Desktop\Path";
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*exp.zip",System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

if(files.Length > 0)
{
    foreach(string file in files)
    {
        string result;
        result = Path.GetFileName(file);

        // my code
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            var destination1 = @"C:\Users\orly.simbulan\Desktop\destination1\";
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destination1, result);
            File.Copy(file, destFile, true);
            //System.IO.File.Copy(file, destFile, true);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the problem sample image 
[sample image have file is already exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3CD4.jpg)

Comment: what did you try so far? some code will be helpful

Comment: // my code
                        if (File.Exists(file))
                        {
                            var destination1 = @"C:\Users\orly.simbulan\Desktop\destination1\";

                            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destination1, result);

                            
                            File.Copy(file, destFile, true);


                            //System.IO.File.Copy(file, destFile, true);

                        }

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: there is no error. the problem the method is not use i dont know why. my new files not overwrite the old files..

Comment: So, you doing something wrong. Are you sure, path is correct?

Comment: yes the path is correct. i tried many times but i locate it manually

Comment: I don't understand how the image you linked would be related to your code. `1.jpg` doesn't match the `*exp.zip` pattern.

Comment: I fix already my problem thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.Copy(path, destination, true);
```

Comment: // my code
                        if (File.Exists(file))
                        {
                            var destination1 = @"C:\Users\orly.simbulan\Desktop\destination1\";

                            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destination1, result);

                            
                            File.Copy(file, destFile, true);


                            //System.IO.File.Copy(file, destFile, true);

                        }

Comment: file.copy method not overwrite my old files.